# ViewStub does not show?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-relativelayout, viewstub

i have a Relativelayout `rl_root` that contains some views and a buton, when the button is pressed a method called `showConfigStubView` is invoked and it is to make the layout `rl_root` disappears and a `viewStub` should replace this viewGroup `rl_root`.

At run ime, when the method `showConfigStubView` is invoked, the viewGroup `rl_root`disappears and the `viewStub` does not show ever.

int the `showConfigStubView` is call `View.gone` to make the `rl_root` disappears and then create a new `Viewstub` programmatically `viewStub = new ViewStub(getActivity());` and then created a realtiveLayout with its parameter and then added the `ViewStub` to the new RelativeLayout and then inflated the `viewStub` with its respective layout.

please have a look at the code below, the methods `showConfigStubView` explains how I invoke the `ViewStub`

**main layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rl_root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

<RadioGroup 
    android:id="@+id/rg_mqtt_config_choice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:checkedButton="@+id/rb_used_configs">
    <RadioButton 
        android:id="@+id/rb_used_configs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/rb_used_configs"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_new_configs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/rb_new_configs" />
</RadioGroup>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btn_connect"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rg_mqtt_config_choice"
    android:text="@string/btn_connect"/>
```

**ViewStub**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tvSubView_ip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/tvSubView_ip"/>
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/etSubView_ip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvSubView_ip"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:hint="@string/etSubView_ip_hint"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tvSubView_port"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvSubView_ip"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/tvSubView_port"/>
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/etSubView_port"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvSubView_port"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etSubView_ip"
    android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
    android:hint="@string/etSubView_port_hint"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tvSubView_clientID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvSubView_port"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/tvSubView_clientID"/>
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/etSubView_clientID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvSubView_clientID"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etSubView_port"
    android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
    android:hint="@string/etSubView_clientID_hint"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tvSubView_KATimer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvSubView_clientID"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/tvSubView_KATimer"/>
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/etSubView_KATimer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvSubView_KATimer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etSubView_clientID"
    android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
    android:hint="@string/etSubView_KATimer_hint"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cbSubView_CleanSession"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvSubView_KATimer"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="@string/cbSubView_CleanSession"/>
```

**method showConfigStubView**:

```
protected void showConfigStubView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.rl_Root.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    viewStub = new ViewStub(getActivity());

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams 
            ((int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    params.topMargin = 10;
    viewStub.setLayoutParams(params);
    //rl_Root.addView(viewStub);

    viewStub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.mqttconfig_subtree);
    relativeLayout.addView(viewStub);
    View inflated = viewStub.inflate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that, viewStub should always belong to a non-null ViewGroup or Layout. seeting your RelativeLayout visibility to `Gone`is considered as there is no viewGroup to which your viewStub should belong. I suggest to try the following:

```
protected void showConfigStubView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.rg_ConfigChoice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    this.btn_connect.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    this.viewStub = new ViewStub(getActivity());
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams 
            ((int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    this.viewStub.setLayoutParams(params);
    this.rl_Root.addView(viewStub);
    this.viewStub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.mqttconfig_subtree);
    View inflated = viewStub.inflate();
}
```